# Differences between file and content Uri in Android

Tags: android

Hi I want to understand the difference between a file Uri (starting with file:///) and content Uri (starting with content:///) in Android.
A use case where I have got a Uri is when we want a user to select a file picker using the Android file picker. The Uri I have always got was content Uri and never a file Uri.
I want to understand the difference between the two and when could one get a content Uri versus a file Uri.

Comment: A file uri is just a file system path with prefix file://. So it is just a path you could handle in the classic way if you wanna read the file. No one else involved.

Comment: With a content scheme uri a content provider is involved wich will deliver you the bytes of the file if you try to open and read it using a content resolver.

Comment: When you share a `file:///` link the receiving app simply opens the file. When you use `content:///` the receiving app "talks" with your app (IPC). For `content:///` you have too implement some interfaces. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics